# React.createElement: type is invalid expected a string

Tags: react-native

I am newbie with react native, I trying to make restaurant app, but getting the following error in the browser console:

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

so what I am missing? it telling me that the  error is in the render method but i can't figure it out

app.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar, Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import { StackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import { constants } from 'expo';
import HomeScreen from './src/home';
import DetailScreen from './src/detail';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                headerBackTitle: 'Back',
            },
          },
    Detail: { screen: DetailScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
              title: 'Detail',
          },
        }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

home.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar, Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state  = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
      refreshing: false,
      base_url: "http://localhost:8000/api"
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDataFromApi();

  }

  fetchDataFromApi = ()  => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/api.json";

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {

        this.setState({
          data: res,
          error: null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading : false });
      })
  };

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.fetchDataFromApi();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%",
          marginTop: "3%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail',
              {name: `${item.name}`, menu: `${item.menu}`,
              img: `${this.state.base_url}${item.photo}`,
              address: `${item.address}`})}
              avatar={<Avatar
                      source={{uri: `${this.state.base_url}${item.photo}`}}
                      onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
                      containerStyle={{marginBottom: 2}}
                      avatarStyle={{resizeMode: "cover"}}
                      width={140}
                      height={130}
                />}
              title={`${item.name}`}
              titleStyle={{ fontSize: 16}}
              titleContainerStyle = {{ marginLeft: 120 }}
              subtitle={<View style={styles.subtitleView}>
            <Text style={styles.menuText}>{item.menu}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.locText}>{item.address}</Text>
            </View>}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, marginBottom: 20 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}

        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
   subtitleView: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 110
  },
  menuText: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    color: 'grey'
  },
  locText: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    color: 'grey',
    marginTop: 6,
    fontSize: 12
  },
  titleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  restaurantImage: {
    width: 600,
    height: 800
  }
});
```

package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: can you show your `package.json`

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: when did you start getting this error? Like after adding which block? Can you revert what you have added. It will be easier for you to debug what you have done wrong.

Comment: I added the app.js

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports you probably have imported the wrong component which doesn't exist.

I suspect it's `List` which you imported from react-native-elements, I think there is no component named `List`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you are importing stackNavigator wrongly

change

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

to

```
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is in app.js remove StackNavigator  from import { StackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

Comment: change import { StackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; to import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';